# Excel 2016: Copy value as well as format with formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

Excel 2016: I am looking for a formula or VB script to Copy value as well as format. i.e. if I write =A2, in cell A3; then A3 contain same value and format as A2.

Comment: Formula cannot. VBA only. Value don't need to be copied - it is already correctly calculated. Copy format only.

Comment: What kind of Format you are suppose to copy Number,, Date & Time  or Font & Colors ?

Answer (score 0):

None of the Excel functions, copies format of a cell along with the value to another cell.

Either you have to use features like,

**C**onditional Formatting, **F**ormat Painter, 
or, the **C**ell Format options.

Or you can use VBA to references cells and their formatting.

*You may use VBA Macro like this:*

```
Sub CopyPasteFormat()

Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Range("A1").Select
Selection.Copy

Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Range("C1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

End Sub
```

*Also, Excel allows to apply cell format with the formula.*

**Few are:**

`=TEXT(A1,"##.00")`

`=TEXT(B1, "DD/MM/YY")`

`=TEXT(B1, "HH:MM")`

`=TEXT(B1, "DD/MM/YY  HH:MM:SS")`

*Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.*

Comment: Thanks, That VBA has solved the problem.

Comment: Glad to help you @HaiderModi,, if you wish now you can accept it as answer as well up vote also☺